# Animate an image becoming the background

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a div with 2 image elements, and I want to animate the background replacing the current background, and the logo/title replacing the current page title (an h1 element) when the div is clicked.

This is the div structure:

```html
<div class="category ce" onclick="openCategory('macos',this)">
  <img class="cbg" src="images/categories/bg/macos.png">
  <img class="cfg" src="images/categories/logo/macos.png">
</div>
```

[Demo of what I want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2xrb.png)

Here is the [full code](https://github.com/ItsFoxDev/wallpack) if you want it

I've tried setting `position:fixed` and `inset:0px` with `transition:all .2s` but it doesn't animate at all.
[What it looks like](https://imgur.com/a/XrO3R1Q)

Comment: I am not entirely sure how you want to animate it. Does it need to enlarge and fade into the background? If yes, you may want to animate the `scale` property of `.category.ce:hover` in your stylesheet. Also I'd recommend not using GitHub in your question. As you or others change or remove the project, people can no longer see the example you included in your question.